# Shuffling buttons

Tags: java, jbutton, shuffle

I am trying to shuffle buttons on empty border with a shuffle key. All buttons positions set manually. I want to be like that "banks' virtual keyboards". Just numbers between 0-9.

```
int [][]b = {{6, 5},{66, 5},{126, 5},{6, 68},{66, 68},{126, 68},{6, 131},{66, 131},{126, 131},{6, 194}};
```

They are my coordinates. Just shuffle them on my empty border. I know how do I on grid layout.

Comment: what are you trying ??

Comment: You could have an Array or a 2D Array (Grid) where each index represents a position on the screen, and each element is a reference to a specific button. Then shuffle this array! That's all I can say from what you've given.

Comment: Do you have to shuffle the buttons or their content? Changing the content and resetting the `ActionListener` of each button seems more efficient than removing, shuffling and re-adding each button to the component.

Comment: I don't want to remove them but I don't know how to do it. Any method for adding all buttons into a list and add into contentpane after ?

Comment: @dangerarea006 include the code that creates the button and adds it to the parent container and we might be able to provide better solutions.